# Need some good tutorials for iBatis

Tags: java, ibatis

I've searched a bit but can't seem to find a good resource that gives the basics with this framework. What sites would you recommend?

Comment: This is a good question for programmar stackexchange.

Comment: You can refer the **Loiane Groner**'s site. It has a very clean example that are uploaded to github http://loianegroner.com/?s=ibatis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iBatis is very light-weight framework without much frills. But iBatis developers has moved to create more elegant version of iBatis, called *myBatis*. So, if your organization is not already using iBatis, I would suggest to look into [myBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/about.html).

As far as learning resources are concerned. There are a couple (and you don't need many)

1. [iBatis in Action](http://www.manning.com/begin/) Book. It's 2007 edition, but it's suffice.
2. [iBatis SQL Maps](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/pdf/iBATIS-SqlMaps-2_en.pdf) -- a free resource
3. [MyBatis User Guide](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/downloads/detail?name=MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf) -- this is only available reference for myBatis, not complete but sufficient to get started. *Almost* everything that's true for iBatis is also true for myBatis. There are some new stuffs.

Join mailing list of myBatis, you may get help on iBatis as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yep and there are some interesting Q/As in stack as well. Have a peep at some questions

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iBatis+tutorial

Sometime back I had some trouble using the iBatis queryForMap using an iterating list of parameters see answer [How do you map a List<string> in iBatis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127992/how-do-you-map-a-liststring-in-ibatis/5377452#5377452)

Another link I'm having a peep at the moment http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/06/ibatis-tutorial-inheritance-strategies.html